# How to create an error if a folder is not empty

Tags: excel, vba

I am copying the previous years folder and creating a new folder based on the year a user inputs into an InputBox. If the new folder that would be created already exists I want to send them to an error section and display a message.  Below is what I thought should do that, but it isn't. It goes straight to start even if the new folder exists and there are multiple files in it. Err stays at 0

```
If Dir(NewYearFolder) = "" Then
    GoTo Start
Else
    Err = 1
    GoTo BadInput
End If
```

Comment: It would help if we had a better idea of where `Start` and `BadInput` line labels are... please read [mcve] and [edit] your post accordingly.

Comment: That said if `Dir` means to look for folders and not files, it needs a `vbDirectory` argument.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon They're both below this in the sub. I don't see how it would be pertinent information. I just need to send to one label or the other dependent upon their being files in the folder or not.

Comment: `Err` is a global-scope function that yields an `ErrObject`. What's `Err = 1` supposed to be doing? Is `Err` declared in that procedure's scope? `GoTo`-jumping is a massive indicator of poor control flow; the rest of the code might not seem relevant, and indeed might not be for the problem you're having *now*, but I was just trying to help you detangle the spaghetti, but eh, what do I know.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon  Thank you for the help. This is the only use of Goto. I did not know Err was a function. I was simply using it to define my errors as an integer. I will change the variable name

Comment: I'd warmly recommend putting up your full working code up for review on [codereview.se]; you'd be surprised how a working piece of code can end up after another pair of eyes has gone through it, let alone with everything there is to learn from CR answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If Dir(NewYearFolder, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    GoTo Start
Else
    Err = 1
    GoTo BadInputs
End If
```

Got it